# Axon not able to connect to Azure Event hub using Kafka protocol

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub, axon

```
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:377) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.readFromSocketChannel(SslTransportLayer.java:205) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.read(SslTransportLayer.java:528) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:94) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:424) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:385) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:651) [kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:572) [kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:483) [kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:539) [kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:307) [kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:238) [kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:na]
```

Events gets published with plain kafka client program. But not with Axon. Following are the configurations

```
axon.kafka.client-id=producer
axon.kafka.default-topic=test
axon.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix=deafultTxPrefix
axon.kafka.bootstrap-servers=****.servicebus.windows.net:9093
axon.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
axon.kafka.properties.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
axon.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="Endpoint=sb://****.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessPolicy;SharedAccessKey=***********;EntityPath=test";
```

Other dependecies:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.1.4.RELEASE
org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the logs for the producer properties logged both with and without Axon? I think there might be a property that's not correctly 'forwarded' to the producer with Axon.

Comment: Hi Gerard Klijs, thanks for the reply. There is no difference in producer configuration in both cases.

Comment: Update: Event with plain kafka-client, with transaction enabled seeing the similar issue. Axon uses transactional mode by default.

Comment: If you remove the `axon.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix` property, it should no longer be transactional.